# Dock utility that shows current energy usage

Tags: battery, dock, power-management

The Activity Monitor.app has its own section all for energy consumption. This is really great for finding the aggregate worst offenders. The cpu section is great for finding the worst offender at any given moment. But whenever I notice that the battery is going out way too quickly, it is always a bit too late, and the Dock icon showing CPU does not really light up noticeably when some process just uses 15-20% constantly. This makes the CPU unable to enter idle state and just sucks the life out of the battery.

Is there a monitor that can show me the current wattage used? Would be so much more useful.

Comment: The first issue I see with this is you could have an app that basically sits just above idle except for absolutely taxing the WiFi or Bluetooh power.  That would draw a ton of power and won’t be “attached” to the process.  Also, how would you calculate *wattage* on a per app basis.  The SMC can only report on the (total) amps being drawn by the *system* which includes functions outside the CPU (i.e. powering a USB port).  It’s not broken out by app.

Comment: @Allan Thanks for the reply. Note that I am not asking for per-app power usage anywhere in the post. I can add the word total or aggregated to the subject and the question in the body if that helps. I am only interested in whether my Macbook consumes 2 or 32 watts at any given time: the Activity Monitor will then quickly guide me to the details of which app :)